# My Minecraft Bedwars keeps glitching me out when I am building up or walking up something

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft Bedwars keeps glitching me out when I am either building straight up, or when I am walking up something. When I build straight up to attack someone or to get safe, it usually just keeps glitching me into the block I placed down or just glitches me out into the void. And the other problem is, when I am walking up something that isn't straight, it usually just takes me back to the start of the steps, and that usually gets me killed. How do I fix this problem? if there is no solution then, how am I supposed to get good at the game?

Answer (score 2):

This is called "lag". Try to get a better internet connection, for example using a LAN cable.